# Black bar where the applicationBar was on BackKey

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, application-bar

My app has a white background and a blue applicationBar on some pages. But everytime I tap the backbutton and leave a page the applicationBar goes down and leaves a black bar of the same size. At the same time all other elements disappear so I see most of the screen white and a black bar on the bottom for a second or so (slow device).
Is there a way to avoid this?

I define my applicationBar in the xaml and on one page I switch two bars in the c#-code.
nothing special.

I tried to remove it before leaving but it didn't help:

```
void PageBackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
}
```

Comment: What device are you testing on? What is the phone's theme and what is the page's background?

Comment: The phone is a Lumia 520, the OS is set to a black background, the app must have a white background and dark elements on it. I checked what other apps do and it seems to be possible. At least all the Nokia-Stuff does it right. When you press the back-key the applicationBar disappears ind you see the background-color of the page before a new one is loaded.